# Any Suggestions for designing Memory Game in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am a beginner to Objective c and I am designing a memory game in objective c where I have 5x5 button grid. 
I am unable to decide on how to design the application.

If I use OpenGL I need to program a lot.

Should I use OpenGL to design the game or do you have any suggestions of using a UIView or any existing controls?

- I have a limit of displaying 3 x 3 buttons on a view and when the user scrolls/swipes I have to display next/previous buttons in the grid with animation.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at SpriteKit, nice, clean and simple  API for 2D-stuff...

Comment: Thank you @nickfalk. I will try with sprite kit

Comment: For such a simple game, using OpenGL or UIKit doesn't make a big difference, provided you know the frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

You can develop it in native iOS using gestures with views. I had made a demo game with the same idea. Tiles puzzle and combining parts of an object to complete shape (i.e. car shape from parts). You can take help from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html).